# Kivy Subtext in TextInput

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Look at the image below and see the faint text.

[image: Text Input Field with Faint Text]

Is it possible to add the text (I dont need an image) in the background of the textinput field in kivy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TextInput has a `hint_text` property that does this.